# VBA macro to delete rows quickly

Tags: excel, optimization, row, vba

I have several really large excel data files and I need to go through them all and delete all rows where the value of the cell in column T is 1. Right now my code looks like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("T5", "T900000")
        If cell.Value = 1 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

It seems to be working, but takes forever to run and I'm going to have to do this a bunch of times. Is there a better way of doing this, or some way to optimize what I already have to make it run faster?

Comment: `Range([T5], [T5].End(xlDown))` will select all contiguous cells with values in them starting at `T5`. Unless you really have 900k lines this is bound to be much faster...

Comment: @Floris Yeah, I really have that many cells...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't work as you think... When you delete rows as you iterate through them, you end up skipping rows. Example: imagine your rows have the numbers 1...10 in column A. You look at the first row and decide to delete it. Now you look at the second row. It has the number 3! You never looked at row 2!!

Better method would be to filter the spreadsheet on your criteria for column T, copy it, paste it I to a new worksheet (with formatting etc).

You can turn on macro recording and do this manually; then you will have the exact VBA code. I am sure that will be much faster.

Even if you don't do that, if you want to do a `for each` where you delete things, reverse the order (start at the end and work backwards)

Comment: Floris' approach is definitely the quickest. In a case when you really needed to iterate through the rows, deleting from the bottom up is a good way to speed things up, while avoiding the row reference problem he points out.

Comment: Yes! Filtering the spreadsheet, copying visible cells and pasting them to a new Worksheet is THE answer.

Comment: How do you do a for each in reverse order?  I didn't think there was a way to do this...

Comment: @timbram you actually have to index the loop "manually" - `For i = n To 1 Step -1` etc. there is no direct "reverse for each" in VBA AFAIK.

Comment: @Floris Thanks!  Yeah that is what I thought!  I tried that just now and reversing through the range simplifies my loop and means that I don't have to worry about skipping rows.  However, it is still very slow.

Comment: I will try the filter method.  might be a better way to get around this like the comments above say.  I just don't understand what Excel is doing when I delete a row that takes that long.    Maybe it like re-calcs in the background even though I have calcs turned to manual?  That is one problem I have with VBA some times is that I am not just dealing with simple data types but instead complex objects that are driven by code I can't sometimes see! :)

Comment: It does a recalc and a redraw. Did you try `Applicatiion.ScreenUpdating = False` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use a loop, the following should not skip items. 
I think that @Floris Filter method might be quicker though.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Row = 5
    Set Sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do
        If Sheet.Cells(Row, 20).Value = 1 Then
            Sheet.Rows(Row).Delete xlShiftUp
        Else
            Row = Row + 1
        End If
    Loop While Row <= 900000
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Update**
I've toggled `Application.ScreenUpdating` around the loop, which usually speeds stuff like this up a lot!

Comment: Nice! I think if you find the last cell in column T (rather than "900000") this might be reasonable. +1 for the "delete or increment row" trick!

Comment: You can also disable automatic calculations, on top of disabling screen updates. Running the script backwards (From lastLine to FirstLine step 1) is of up most importance otherwise you skip the next row every time you deleted a row.

Comment: @RobertIlbrink, didn't know about the calculation one. This function will not skip rows though!

Comment: @NickSlash, Disabling calculations and screen updates will make your macro run faster. Otherwise, with every row deletion, the spreadsheet will be recalculated and the updates shown on screen. Even with calculation turned off, you will still skip rows if you run top-down because the row references have changed. row 20 is now row 19 and when you jump to row 20, you missed row 19 (old row 20). When you run the delete loop in the bottom-up loop, you will check rows double after a row has been deleted, but you will be sure that all rows have been deleted.

Comment: Im fully aware of this and my function takes this into account, please read the code.

Answer (score 2):

In case you manage your data like a database and want to delete specific rows out of it and it is possible to filter them, there is a trick to speed up your delete-process. This is very fast in contrast to the simple loop-process:

I compare the times for different examples (with 4806 rows).

- Standard loop-deletion: 2:25
- Range-deletion: 0:20
- Filter-deletion: 0:01

**Example**: I have data in 'Tabelle5' and want to delete specific rows. The data starts at row 6. Every row in column 1, which begin with "OLD#" should be deleted.

1) Here the standard solution (longest time):

```
Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer
Dim strToRemove As String, strToRemoveRange As String
strToRemove = "OLD#"
strToRemoveRange = ""
counter = 0

With Tabelle5
    For i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 6 Step -1
        If Mid(.Cells(i, 1).value, 1, 4) = strToRemove Then
            .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

2) Here the Range solution (middle time):

```
Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer
Dim strToRemove As String, strToRemoveRange As String
strToRemove = "OLD#"
strToRemoveRange = ""
counter = 0

With Tabelle5
    For i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 6 Step -1
        If Mid(.Cells(i, 1).value, 1, 4) = strToRemove Then
            If strToRemoveRange = "" Then
                strToRemoveRange = CStr(i) & ":" & CStr(i)
            Else
                strToRemoveRange = strToRemoveRange & "," & CStr(i) & ":" & CStr(i)
            End If
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
        If counter Mod 25 = 0 Then
            If counter > 0 Then
                .Range(strToRemoveRange).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                strToRemoveRange = ""
                counter = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(strToRemoveRange) > 0 Then
        '.Range(strToRemoveRange).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End With
```

3) Filter solution (shortest time):

```
Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer
Dim strToRemove As String, strToRemoveRange As String
strToRemove = "OLD#"
strToRemoveRange = ""
counter = 0

With Tabelle5
    For i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 6 Step -1
        If Mid(.Cells(i, 1).value, 1, 4) = strToRemove Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next i
    If counter > 0 Then
        .Rows("5:5").AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add( _
            Range("A5"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        .AutoFilter.Sort.Header = xlYes
        .AutoFilter.Sort.MatchCase = False
        .AutoFilter.Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .AutoFilter.Sort.Apply
        .Rows("6:" & CStr(counter + 5)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("5:5").AutoFilter
    End If
End With
```

Here the green lines will be ordered to the top and a range of the green hits will be deleted as a whole. That's the fastest way I know! :-)

I hope it will help someone!

Best regards
Tom

Answer (score 0):

The quickest method I have found is to clear row data (.clear) and then sort.
For example, I want to get rid of page breaks that show as "   ========= "

```
I=20
Do While i <= lRow3
    If Left(Trim(ws3.Cells(i, 1)), 1) = "=" Then
        ws3.Range(Rows(i - 7), Rows(i + 2)).Clear
        'i = i - 7
        'lRow3 = lRow3 - 10
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Now sort then do an xlUp last row (ws3.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row) etc.

Deleting the rows (in one of my files which is 220,000 rows approx.) takes 3 minutes. Clearing the contents takes under 10 seconds.

The problem then becomes how to 'remove' the empty rows if you need to move data from below the rows to one above before this is done. :)

Cheers,
BJ