# Delete Row Loop Optimization VBA

Tags: vba, loops, optimization, excel

The code below was written as part of a random sample generator. Based on the total number of occurences, it calculates the sample size and reduces the population to the sample size. Right now I'm doing this by deleting the difference between the total and the sample size. I'd like to see if there's a better way of going about this. I'm getting a sample of each value in a user-defined column and working with a large data set, so the sampling ends up taking a few minutes.

Is there way to delete the number of rows I need to all at once instead of having to do them one at a time as seen in the loop below, or a better way to go about this altogether? Thank you!

```
x = (Population - SampleSize)

    If Population > SampleSize Then
        Do Until x = 0
            Workbooks(SourceBook).Sheets(SampleSheet).Columns(StratCol) _
            .Find(What:=SubPop, After:=Cells(SampRows, StratCol), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).EntireRow.Delete

        x = x - 1

        Loop

    End If
```

Comment: yes, there is, but only by adding a formula column as in [How to delete multiple rows without a loop in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431801/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba) - see my answer for a possible solution

Comment: @ForrestA Kindly refer to similar thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375054/vba-macro-to-delete-rows-quickly

Comment: yes, AUtoFilter/Advanced Filter is another option **without a loop** where SpecialCells doesn't have to be used

Comment: To clarify, I'm mainly looking for this to achieve the desired result quicker. Whether or not this is a loop doesn't matter to me, though I do appreciate the diversity in approaches to this problem. Also, keep in mind that this is deleting a specific portion of the rows with matching criteria and not all of them. Thank you very much for the suggestions! When I get a chance to give them a spin I'll let you know which one works best for me.

Comment: @ForrestA any feedback yet>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a range that contains multiple non-contiguous rows and then delete all of them at once.  This will probably speed things up a bit.

```
x = (Population - SampleSize)

dim MyRange as Range

If Population > SampleSize Then
    Do Until x = 0
        if MyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyRange = Workbooks(SourceBook).Sheets(SampleSheet).Columns(StratCol) _
                .Find(What:=SubPop, After:=Cells(SampRows, StratCol), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).EntireRow
        Else
            Set MyRange = Application.Union(MyRange, Workbooks(SourceBook).Sheets(SampleSheet).Columns(StratCol) _
                .Find(What:=SubPop, After:=Cells(SampRows, StratCol), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).EntireRow)
        End If
        x = x - 1
    Loop
    MyRange.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

for this solution a loop **can** be avoided.

Just add an extra column creating an error which can be found using **SpecialCells** as below:

```
Range("IA1:IA" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(A:A = """ & SubPop & """,NA(),"""") "
```

then you use SpecialCells to identify the rows matching SupPop, and delete the entire row!

```
Range("IA1:IA" & Range("A65536").end(xlup).row).specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlup
```

Finally, clean up/delete the extra formula colummn we added at the beginning:

```
Range("IA1:IA" & Range("A65536").end(xlup).row).clear
```

Here is a proper explanation of this technique: [How to delete multiple rows without a loop in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431801/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba)

I hope that helps to get you started

and here is the above code all in one function as *eagerly* requested:

```
Sub deleteRows(ByVal strSubPop As String)
' pass in the string to match (SubPop)
'
    Range("IA1:IA" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(A:A = """ & strSubPop & """,NA(),"""") "
'    
    ' for debugging and testing just select the rows where a match is found
    Range("IA1:IA" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Select
 '   
    ' when ready, UNCOMMENT the below line
   ' Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
  '  
    ' after testing just use this line to select the rows and delete in one step:
    ' Range("IA1:IA" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
   '  
    ' now clean up Column IA
    Range("IA1:IA" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    Range("A1").Select
'
End Sub
```

so what is that code doing?

First your requirement is to delete rows matching **SubPop**

1. The first line adds a formula in Column IA that matches SubPop found
   in Column A
2. The next line finds all those rows then deletes them
3. the final line cleans up

Philip

Comment: I guess most of ppl know SpecialCells. Kindly use it against a value and show me if it works. Waiting for your reply eagerly.

Comment: the above code uses the value SubPop. If found in column A then the formula returns an NA# error code in the cells in column IA. SpecialCells searches in Column IA for errors (NA#) then the range command returns the entire row that takes the Delet method!

Comment: @user2063626 sorry there was a bug in the line adding a formula to column IA, this has now been fixed!

Comment: @ForrestA though i would work its a wrong way of doing the above task.

Comment: @user2063626 the OP asked for a solution **avoiding** a loop. It's not a workaround, it's a possible solution.

Comment: what if the range A:A has a text " mango" and strSubPop ="mango" what would be the result ??

Comment: well, you could always try it, but in your example, then all the matching rows are selected and deleted, **which is what the user wants**

Comment: of course, the criteria are determined by the OP, and the Column A:A **is just an example** - this needs to be *modified* by the OP

Comment: I understand these are examples but i just pointed a situation where the logic can fail and may lead to misleading data.

Answer (score -1):

For this situation loop cannot be avoided.
Try below code.

```
 Dim rng As Range
    x = (Population - SampleSize)

    If Population > SampleSize Then
        Do Until x = 0

            With Workbooks(SourceBook).Sheets(SampleSheet)
                Set rng = .Columns(StratCol).Find(What:=SubPop, After:=Cells(SampRows, StratCol))
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    rng.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With

            x = x - 1
        Loop
    End If
```

Comment: loop can be avoided, see my answer