# start the loop or don't iterate. Continue for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a cell range and delete the entire row if a cell doesn't match a certain pattern. Since deleting a row skips an iteration step I am trying to use 'Continue for' so I would delete a row and not move to the next cell but rerun for the same cell value to not skip a row. Unfortunately Continue for doesn't seem to be recognized. (not sure what reference to include) This is what I am doing:

```
   Set Values = Sheets("A").Range(Sheets("A").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("A").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
    For Each Cell In Values
         If Not Cell.Value Like "*pattern*" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Delete
            Continue For
         End If
    Next Cell
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Typically when deleting rows you'd start at the last row and work upwards.

Comment: Doing it in reverse is easier but it is possible to do it top down providing you keep track of the row number yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839622/vba-macro-to-delete-unchecked-rows-using-marlett-check/15839773#15839773

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim x as long

Set Values = Sheets("A").Range(Sheets("A").Cells(2, 1), _
                               Sheets("A").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))

For x = Values.cells.count to 1 step -1
     With Values.Cells(x)
         If Not .Value Like "*pattern*" Then .EntireRow.Delete
     End With    
Next x
```