# VBA - deleting rows with conditions in loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have to delete all rows that have to cells equal in VBA excel. Here is what i wrote:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
j = Rows.Count
For i = 1 To j
    If Cells(i, 17).Value = Cells(i, 19).Value Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
```

But this code is not deleting every line I am looking for. If there are 2 rows with matches the conditions respectively, Excel jumps to another one and leaves this (which is logical), I do not know how to adapt this loop to coming back and delete every searched line

Comment: always loop backwards when deleting rows `For i = j To 1 Step -1`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375054/vba-macro-to-delete-rows-quickly

Comment: You should check out my answer to [Compare cells to delete rows, value is true but not deleting rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755334/compare-cells-to-delete-rows-value-is-true-but-not-deleting-rows/40755406#40755406).  It demonstrates the effects of deleting while iterating over a loop.

Answer (score 2):

What I am understanding from your code is , it is not iterating all the lines since one of the conditions are getting fulfilled . 
My recommendation is to reverse loop it. Iterate from the last by using **"-1"**

Instead of:

```
For i = 1 To j
    If Cells(i, 17).Value = Cells(i, 19).Value Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
```

Do this:

```
For i = j to 1 Step - 1
    If Cells(i, 17).Value = Cells(i, 19).Value Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
```

Comment: This would be a helpful answer if you demonstrated example code.

Comment: "For i = j To  1 Step -1"
Just put it in you code instead of the existing For loop. Sorry I am not able to test it at this point since my msoffice is having some issue.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot!

Comment: If it really helps you then please like the answer cause that will help others also. :)

Comment: can not by now, because it is new account, but the moment I can I will come back here :)

Comment: @RanadipDutta it's preferable to put a working example of the code in the *answer* itself, not in the comments. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40935051/edit) your answer to be more valuable to others.

Comment: @DavidZemens : I will do that for sure. Once I will work out from system, I would definitely do that. Thanks a lot for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a row you have to decrement the value of i and update the value of j.
Because when you delete a row:

- the following row is now at the i position
- the number of rows (j) is reduced by 1 row

Comment: Good explanation. This is one possible solution, but the generally preferred approach is to do backwards iteration (e.g., `For i = 100 to 1 Step - 1`), rather than decrementing a loop counter variable.